# How to run a TestNG test as many times as a parametrized one?

Tags: testng

I have one test class with two methods, one is parametrized and the second one is not. 
I want the second one to run as many times as the parametrized one does. I know it is possibile to annotate also the second method with "@DataProvider", but does anybody know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the non parameterized method from the parameterized one.